# Logback config : pattern for LoggingEventPatternJsonProvider

Tags: java, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I am trying to programmatically add an LogstashUdpSocketAppender, and I am unable to create a layout with a working pattern

```
private Layout<ILoggingEvent> getLayout() {

    LoggingEventCompositeJsonLayout newLayout = new LoggingEventCompositeJsonLayout();

    LoggingEventPatternJsonProvider patternProvider = new LoggingEventPatternJsonProvider();
    patternProvider.setPattern("{ \"field1\":\"value\" , \"message\":\"%message\"}");

    JsonProviders<ILoggingEvent> providers = new JsonProviders<ILoggingEvent>();        
    providers.addProvider(patternProvider);

    newLayout.setLineSeparator("SYSTEM");
    newLayout.setProviders(providers);

    return newLayout;

}
```

But this does not work, it outputs

> {"field1":"value","message":"%PARSER_ERROR[message]"}

If put the same pattern in a XML config file, it works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/issues/388

Setting the context on the LoggingEventPatternJsonProvider patternProvider patternProvider fixed my issue.

```
patternProvider.setContext(ContextSelectorStaticBinder.getSingleton().getContextSelector().getDefaultLoggerContext());
```